# Epson L355 - Cannot print any document!

Tags: 16.04, printing, epson

I just started using Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 and after setting everything up, I then installed my printer. The driver itself installed smoothly without any problem and it showed up in the printer menu.

But sadly it couldn't print any document. Even trying to print the test-page was merely a dream. When I looked at the Print Queue, the document actually was sent there, but in a second it got completed without any of them being printed.

I can use the printer alright in win10.

What's wrong, eh?

Comment: Did you download the linux drivers from epson.com?

Comment: lsb and lsb-printers is not available in 16.04 which is what the epson drivers use to print. How familiar are you with repositories, dpkg, apt-get etc?

Comment: I installed it using the printers menu > add printer. When I searched this issue I saw lots people can't even install the driver, but somewhat odd I installed it right out of the box without doing any particular step.

Comment: Not so familiar. But I can try. So what should I do then?

Comment: Actually, that's okay. I wrote an answer below.

Comment: Okay, go ahead and run the 5th command and the 6th command to return your system to a normal state and then run  `sudo apt-get -f install` .

Comment: Again, it is important you run `sudo sed -i 's/wily/xenial/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` and then `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Well I tried the other duplicate and it worked. Now I can print all the way I want. Thanks a bunch @mchid

Comment: Awesome!  Not to sound like a broken record but if you didn't run the sed command from my previous comment. Also, you do have a backup copy of the original sources list at /etc/apt/backuplist if you ever run into issues with your /etc/apt/sources.list file.